# What Earth is the Flash from?

Tags: dc, comics, the-flash

In the comics, is Barry Allen aka The Flash from the same Earth as Batman and Superman, and which Earth is that?

Comment: The comics are a separate continuity from the current movies are a separate continuity from the nolanverse are a separate continuity from the cw shows are a separate continuity from the cartoons. Simple, no?

Comment: You're mixing up the DCEU and the CW Arrowverse.

Comment: Flash (the TV character) exists completely separate from Flash (the movie character); the characters from the movie aren't from any of the "Ëarths" they talk about in the TV show.

Comment: That we KNOW of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To really answer this, you need to identify a time period (and, possibly, a set of titles).

### TL;DR

Most DC realities with both a Batman and a Flash have Bruce Wayne as Batman; many have Barry Allen as the Flash, although one or two have the Flash as a man named Jay Garrick, and others as Barry's nephew, Wally West.

### 1938 - approx. 1955:

Basically, all DC stories took place on a single Earth (later called Earth-2, naturally). Bruce Wayne was Batman, Superman was Clark Kent (Kryptonian name initially Kal-L, then later Kal-El). Flash was Jay Garrick, Green Lantern was Alan Scott (a man with a unique magic ring); the Atom was a short guy who worked out a lot named Al Pratt; Hawkman was a guy named Carter Hall, who was a reincarnated Egyptian prince (or something like that) who could fly by using a special belt (possible made of something called *Nth metal*, can't recall at this point); etc.

### 1955 - 1986:

The beginning point for this was *SHOWCASE* #4, the first appearance of the "silver-age" Flash, Barry Allen. Except for a few characters (Superman, Batman, Wonder Woman, and I think Aquaman and Green Arrow), most of the DC heroes hadn't been seen in several years. Julius Schwartz is generally credited with beginning to re-introduce new versions of these heroes. Flash/Barry was followed by Green Lantern (Hal Jordan, a test pilot who became a space cop, one of 3600 people (give or take) with rings that were theoretically science-based); the Atom (Ray Palmer, a scientist who found some dwarf-star matter that allowed him to shrink down to the size of atomic particles, and change his weight/mass as well); Hawkman (Katar Hol, a policeman from the planet Thanagar who could fly with the aid of an Nth metal belt, who came to Earth chasing a Thanagarian criminal and decided to stick around and call himself Carter Hall).

After a few years, there was a story where Barry Allen penetrated a dimensional barrier, and found himself on a version of Earth where the Flash was a guy in his 40s named Jay Garrick! It turns out that all the adventures we'd seen prior to the mid-50s happened in this other dimension, and all the alternate versions of the various heroes were still around there.

Barry's Earth was referred to as Earth-1, and Jay's as Earth-2 (yes, I know that means that Earth-2 came first; however, Earth-1 was where most currently published stories were happening).

Not long after this, the Earth-2 heroes reformed their main super-hero group (the Justice Society of America), and started meeting the main Earth-1 super-hero group (the Justice League of America) every summer.

As time went by, facts about the various characters that were canon when they first appeared but changed over time were established to be true for the Earth-2 heroes. Superman is the best example; DC went back to saying that Superman's Kryptonian name was Kal-L; that Clark Kent worked for the newspaper "The Daily Star", not "The Daily Planet"; and some stories at least limited him to the abilities he had very early in his career (he could jump really high and far rather than flying; bullets would bounce off him, but an artillery shell might not; etc.).

In the second meeting of the JLA and JSA, they interacted with the inhabitants of a third Earth (called, creatively enough, Earth-3), featuring evil versions of Superman (Ultraman), Batman (Owlman), Wonder Woman (Superwoman), the Flash (Johnny Quick), and Green Lantern (Power Ring). Some were definitively established *not* to have the same alter-egos (Ultraman was a human astronaut who gained powers from exposure to Kryptonite, for instance), so I don't think this Batman and Flash were Bruce and Barry.

DC Comics had bought the IP of a number of other comics companies that had failed at some point: Quality Comics (featuring characters like Uncle Sam, Phantom Lady, Plastic Man, and the Blackhawks); Fawcett Publications (best known for the Marvel Family and Captain Marvel (the one who said "Shazam!" and gained the ability of Solomon, Hercules, Atlas, Zeus, Achilles (I think), and Mercury)); and Charlton Comics (featuring characters like Captain Atom, Blue Beetle, and the Question).

We started seeing some of these characters in the 1970s, and each was assigned their own Earth:

- Captain Marvel and the other Fawcett characters lived on Earth-S
- Most of the Quality heroes lived on Earth-X, where the Nazis won WWII (Plastic Man and the Blackhawks had already been seen, presumably on Earth-1). They eventually travelled to Earth-1 and became the Freedom Fighters.
- For an *very* short period of time, the Earth with the Charlton characters was established to be Earth-4.

Other Earths were introduced as well - the only other ones I remember well were Earth-C (home of Captain Carrot and his Amazing Zoo Crew, where the "people" are all anthropomorphic animals) and Earth-C-Minus (Home of the Justa Lotta Animals, anthropomorphic animal versions of the JLA)

### 1986-2011:

In 1986, DC celebrated their 50th year publishing comics (Superman and Batman didn't come along until 1938, but there were comics before them). Those annual JLA/JSA crossovers were always titled "Crisis on ", so they created the ultimate crossover, *CRISIS ON INFINITE EARTHS*. They featured characters from each of the Earths mentioned above. They also decided that having all these different Earths was confusing, and reduced things down to just one Earth, which was a merger of Earth-1, Earth-2, Earth-4, Earth-S, and Earth-X. The Earth-2 characters who had exact copies on Earth-1 (Superman, Batman, Wonder Woman, Green Arrow, and Aquaman) went away.

This probably made sense at the time; practically speaking as far as making sense of things, it was a complete nightmare. Some characters carried on almost completely unchanged (like Bruce Wayne/Batman). Some were given new histories (Superman's adoptive parents were still alive; he never had a career as Superboy; his powers were toned down some, etc.). Some were completely restarted (in the post-Crisis reality, Wonder Woman first appeared in 1987, and had no adventures before that). And a couple were killed during the Crisis - most notably Supergirl, and the Barry Allen Flash. Barry's nephew, Wally West (previously known as Kid Flash), became the Flash for the next 20 years or so. Some characters were revamped as much as five years after the Crisis (with Hawkman being one of the last; they had a new version of Katar Hol travel to Earth from a far more dystopian Thanagar around 1991, in the *HAWKWORLD* mini-series; leaving the question of who the Hawkman who'd appeared during the past 5 years was).

Over time, chinks began to develop in the "one Earth" concept.

- In the 2000s, Grant Morrison brought back Earth-3 (now called Earth-2 (just to make things simple) in the graphic novel of the same name).
- The ending to the *52* weekly comic book, depicting the aftermath of DC's *INFINITE CRISIS* series and some of the events that happened in the following year (all the regular comics skipped ahead one year following *INFINITE CRISIS*), a limited multiverse was reinstated, with 52 different Earths. Variant versions of Earth-X, Earth-S, Earth-4, Earth-3, and other prominent DC alternate realities were established as existing. Generally, the Earth where all the mainstream DC books were set is considered to be Earth-0. (Note, however, that the main DC Earth continued to be the "merged Earth" formed during the 1986 Crisis - Captain Marvel, the Blue Beetle, the Freedom Fighters, and the JSA and JLA were all still in one place).
- DC has published a handful of graphic novels featuring complete reinventions of various characters (as seen in *SUPERMAN: EARTH ONE*, *BATMAN: EARTH ONE*, *WONDER WOMAN: EARTH ONE*, and *TEEN TITANS: EARTH ONE*). These are commonly considered as being set on Earth-1 of the "new multiverse" mentioned above.

An aside: Bruce Wayne was missing and presumed dead following the *FINAL CRISIS* event in 2007-2008. He was actually displaced in time, and eventually made it back to the present. Dick Grayson, the first Robin (and now Nightwing) took over the Batman identity while he was gone, and continued in the role alongside Bruce Wayne for a year or two, being the Batman of Gotham City while Bruce started up some international characters to be local versions of Batman in their home countries (as seen in the *BATMAN INCORPORATED* series).

Another aside: in a big event story in 2009-2010 (*BLACKEST NIGHT*), several dead characters were brought back to life. This included the Barry Allen Flash.

During this timeframe, DC published a large number of alternate reality stories, under the heading of "Elseworlds". These featured familiar characters in different settings (a Batman who was a vampire; a Superman who landed in the USSR, instead of the USA; etc.). It wasn't always clear whether other characters were around in these alternate realities. Sometimes there might be a Batman who we'd recognize as Superman in the mainstream DC reality; often, there was a Bruce Wayne who might or might not be called Batman, but usually was functionally. Since Wally West was the Flash during most of this time, he was the Flash in some of these; Barry Allen might be mentioned as having been the Flash in the past, or might not. Some of these realities were visited in multiple one-shot stories, or in mini-series; none were an on-going series.

### 2011 - 2016:

In 2011, another DC event storyline, *FLASHPOINT*, changed things yet again. Barry Allen traveled back in time to prevent his mother from dying. Unfortunately, this resulted in an extremely different timeline, where a young Bruce Wayne was killed in a holdup, leading his mother to go insane, and his father to become Batman. The Flash managed to basically reverse this series of events, restoring most characters to recognizable forms, but with some small differences (Superman's adoptive parents went back to having died when he was a young man; the Huntress and Power Girl were on the main DC Earth, but came from Earth-2/Earth 2; etc.) This relaunched DC Universe was referred to as the "New 52" (referring to the fact that there were 52 monthly titles being published and taking place in this reality be DC at the time).

In this version of the DC universe, there were no World War II-era heroes still active as a Justice Society of America. However, a series titled *EARTH 2* did present us with a world that had, at one point, had versions of Superman (Clark Kent), Batman (Bruce Wayne), and Wonder Woman, all of whom had died or disappeared several years ago. Now a number of new heroes were appearing - and these were brand-new, young versions of the old Earth-2 characters: a Flash named Jay Garrick, a Green Lantern named Alan Scott, etc.

In 2015, there was a big DC event called *CONVERGENCE*. This is mostly ignorable, except that it featured versions of most of the DC characters from various points in DC's history - pre-Crisis, post-Crisis, Zero Hour (yet another DC event from the mid 1990s that screwed with continuity, to try to clean up after the mess following the 1986 Crisis - didn't make changes to anybody's identity, so I ignored it). Most notably, the resulted in a mini-series that established that the married Superman and Lois Lane from the post-Crisis, pre-Flashpoint DC universe had managed to move to the "New 52" universe - and had a kid, Jonathan.

### 2016+:

In 2016, without a major event, DC yet again revamped their universe. The "New 52" Superman and Lois Lane died; they were replaced by the post-Crisis Superman and Lois Lane mentioned above (and then, somehow, sort of merged with them - haven't read that one yet). So, there's a Superboy now (even if not named as such officially), who's the son of Superman. Dating back to the mid 2000's, Robin is now Damian Wayne, Bruce's son.

The DC universe will now in some form incorporate/acknowledge the reality seen in the *WATCHMEN* mini-series from the mid 1980s. We've been promised the return of the Justice Society of America characters, in a form much closer to their pre-Flashpoint reality rather than the "New 52" *EARTH 2* versions.

Wally West has come back as a second Flash, but the main Flash is still Barry Allen. And, Batman is still Bruce Wayne.

Comment: wow, you wrote a long story. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With respect to DC, their multiverse was established first with "[Flash of Two Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_Two_Worlds)". In it, the Barry Allen Flash was established to be on Earth-1, and the Jay Garrick Flash on Earth-2. Each of these Earths had respective Supermen and Batmen.

This got increasingly complicated until it was solved (albeit temporarily) with a revamp mini-series "[Crisis on Infinite Earths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_on_Infinite_Earths)". This rebooted the continuity for a time, but then it got complicated [again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_Crisis)...

In the comics, this is all basically a creative mechanism to reconcile differing versions of continuity.